# iOS: How to read current network activity level programmatically on iPad/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, networking

I want to determine how many packets or bytes are traveling in & out of my iOS device at any moment. How can that be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have access to that information. Your app is sandboxed from other applications.

Comment: Then I am in a bind. I would have thought this is the kind of info that apps would like to know.

Comment: It is Apple's rules, not mine.

Comment: Daniel i guess it can be done.. check out this app - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/netstat/id400071873?mt=8